# How to make following ARRAYFORMULA with FILTER in certain condition?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I made some formula to lookup date & time in following condition, there is **Start date & time** and **End Date & time**.

```
IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"Auto"),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,FILTER($H$2:$L,$H$2:$H=B2,$K$2:$K<=C2+D2,$L$2:$L>=C2+D2),4,0),VLOOKUP(B2&C2,$G$2:$K,5,0)),VLOOKUP(B2,FILTER($H$2:$L,$H$2:$H=B2,$K$2:$K<=C2+D2,$L$2:$L>=C2+D2),4,0))
```

But, its really take an effort and time when I have to copy paste/ drag down the formula for each row cause I have like thousand data to lookup, I already tried using Arrayformula but it doesn't work cause the filter formula would only filtering the first condition of data.

I you guys have any solutions or the alternatives, I really appreciate it!

Here the link of my spreadsheet : [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxVZ5t2PXwB79C44xmi2p_kyinPcuAIihViVchJuk50/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the need for using FILTER at all.

See my newly added sheet ("Erik Help") and this formula:

`=ArrayFormula({"Shifting Date & Time"; IF(A2:A="",, IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"Auto"),  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C&D2:D, SORT({G2:G&J2:J, J2:J}), 2, TRUE),  VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C, {G2:G&H2:H, K2:K}, 2, TRUE)), VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C&D2:D, SORT({G2:G&J2:J, J2:J}), 2, TRUE)))})`

This is based on the formula you were attempting unsuccessfully to use. I just combined search elements and used a final parameter of `TRUE` in the `VLOOKUP` clauses, operating on `SORT`ed data from your right-side chart.

**ADDENDUM** (After further OP comment):

`=ArrayFormula({"Shifting Date & Time"; IF(A2:A="",, IF(VLOOKUP(B2:B&TEXT(C2:C+D2:D, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"), SORT({G2:G&TEXT(J2:J, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"), G2:G}), 2, TRUE)<>B2:B, "SHIFT ERROR", IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "Auto"), IFERROR( VLOOKUP(B2:B&TEXT(C2:C+D2:D, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"), SORT({G2:G&TEXT(J2:J, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"), J2:J}), 2, TRUE),  VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C, {G2:G&H2:H, K2:K}, 2, TRUE)),  VLOOKUP(B2:B&TEXT(C2:C+D2:D, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"), SORT({G2:G&TEXT(J2:J, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"), J2:J}), 2, TRUE))))})`

This formula is longer mostly because it now included error handling in case a name-date-time is entered that is before any shift that exists in the right-hand list.

I also used `TEXT` to format dates and times differently so that they should now `SORT` in a way that should keep everything in proper order.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you help. But, the reason why I use `FILTER` instead of `SORT`ed the data is because I need **Shifting Date** to be spesifically match within **Start** & **End** date, in case the same person came in a same date but different hour or they came in previous date but doing an Action on the next date. U can check when I add the same name but different hour the formula only read the last sorted one.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goal. But please see my updated formula in the "Erik Help" sheet of your sample spreadsheet (which is also added to my post above). Is this result now what you expect?